# ScintillaNet - detect mouse over

Tags: scintilla

is it possible to react when the mouse is over a word ? Suppose I want to show a bubble with a description of the thing I'm currently hovering. Seems strangely difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible but might be a little hard.

You have the MouseHover event however you don't know what word you hovered so it might be a little hard.

You can get the mouse localization with this:

```
Point mouseLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y)
```

Then if you use a fixed-width type font you know the size of each line/character then you can calculate it.

Some code that helps with position/line transition:

```
var line = scintilla.LineFromPosition(startPos);
startPos = scintilla.Lines[line].Position;
```

scintilla -> Control Name

For a better view try seeing this:

https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Custom-Syntax-Highlighting
https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Basic-Text-Retrieval-and-Modification

Edit:
Not really a good answer soo 2nd try

`[scintilla name].CurrentPosition` -> you can get the word you selected if I'm not mistaken but I don't know if you can do it by hovering.

Then do the interpretation of the word and it might work.

Try reading this:
https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/149

Comment: I understand what you are proposing, but if that's the only way to do it, there seem to be lacking an fundamental feature in the control. I'm afraid the behavior would end up being unstable in certain situations, if I base my computations on the font size. I don't understand why there's not a more direct way to do it.

Comment: Regarding  the second link, I'm not sure how to get the hovering solution from it.

Curiously, it is possible to get the position on the screen from the CurrentPosition : 
new Point(this.PointXFromPosition(CurrentPosition), this.PointYFromPosition(CurrentPosition));

But not conversely. 
However, a crazy idea would be to do a dichotomic search using a random position, and check if the resulting screen position match the current cursor, and then try another position.

Answer (score 0):

3rt Try.
Let's hope it's the best one.

https://github.com/Ahmad45123/AutoCompleteMenu-ScintillaNET

There is AutoCompleteMenu for Scintilla that has a hover property.
I'm not sure how it works but might be what you're searching for.